# How can i use pagination laravel in this situation ?(Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$id)

Tags: laravel

Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$id
This is my Controller function

```
 public function viewQuestion($id){
    $tests=Test::find($id)->paginate(5);
    return view('admin.mocks.questions.all_question',compact('tests'));
}
```

This is my view

```
@foreach($tests->subjects as $key =>$subject)
<tr>
  <td>{{$subject->id}}</td>
  <td>{{$subject->subject_name}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
{{$tests->subjects->links }}
```

Comment: Try `{{$tests->links() }}` or `{{$tests->subjects->links()}}` instead of `{{$tests->subjects->links }}`

Comment: Do you want to paginate test or subject results here?

Comment: No I think error is from Controller ...

Comment: zlatan  Actually Subject.

Comment: try `dd($tests)` in controller @SauravShrestha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the answer you gave me in your comments, to paginate `subjects` you first need to edit your controller code. First find a `test` with given `ID`, then load all `test subjects` and paginate them, instead of paginating single `test` result. Try this:

```
 public function viewQuestion($id){
    $test=Test::find($id);
    $subjects = $test->subjects()->paginate(5);
    return view('admin.mocks.questions.all_question',compact('subjects'));
 }
```

And then, alter your view:

```
@foreach($subjects as $key => $subject)
<tr>
  <td>{{$subject->id}}</td>
  <td>{{$subject->subject_name}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
{{$subjects->links }}
```

PS: Not tested, so let me know if you have any errors.

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist. Now the error is this...
Actually $test=Test::find($id); mean 
example Test 1 where Test1 has various different subject and I wanto to paginate all subjects..

Comment: My bad. I edited my answer. You need to use `$test->subjects()->paginage(5);` instead. Try this.